# displaying two values in a pyqt5 combobox and passing those values

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox

Currently I have two combo boxes, one contains a `sitecode` the other a `folder`, these are read in from a csv which has two columns `SITECODE` and `FOLDER`. Any row contains these two related values. Therefore having them displayed as two individual comboboxes makes no sense.

What I want to do is pass the `SITECODE` and `FOLDER` values to only the one combobox so it displays like: `sitecode | folder`

My current code which needs merging:

```
job_list = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer="data/job_list.csv", header=0)
self.sitecodes = job_list[['SITECODE', 'SITECODE']]
self.comboSiteCodes.addItem("", "")
for row in self.sitecodes.itertuples():
    self.comboSiteCodes.addItem(row.SITECODE, row.SITECODE)
self.comboSiteCodes.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboSiteCodes_index_changed)

self.jobs = job_list[['FOLDER', 'FOLDER']]
self.comboJobs.addItem("", "")
for row in self.jobs.itertuples():
    self.comboJobs.addItem(row.FOLDER, row.FOLDER)
self.comboJobs.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboJobs_index_changed)
```

The values, once selected need to update two lineEdit boxes, one for the `sitecode`, one for the `folder`.

Again, my current code to handle this:

```
def comboSiteCodes_index_changed(self, index):
    global comboSiteCodes_gbl
    comboSiteCodes_gbl = f'{self.comboSiteCodes.itemData(index)}'
    self.lineEditSiteCode.setText('{}'.format(comboSiteCodes_gbl))

def comboJobs_index_changed(self, index):
    global comboJobs_gbl
    comboJobs_gbl = f'{self.comboJobs.itemData(index)}'
    self.lineEditJob.setText('{}'.format(comboJobs_gbl))
```

I've been googling, but I cannot find such a use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add items using a tuple:

```
tuples = job_list[['SITECODE', 'FOLDER']]
for row in tuples.itertuples():
    self.combo.addItem('{} | {}'.format(row.SITECODE, row.FOLDER), (row.SITECODE, row.FOLDER))
self.combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboChanged)
```

Then access the item data likewise:

```
def comboChanged(self, index):
    code, folder = self.combo.itemData(index)
    # ...
```